# My app component is not showing up just loading... from my index.html

Tags: angular

https://plnkr.co/edit/JusdvujkGa3ZVBL5UPCY?p=preview

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.5-dist/css/boostrap.min.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>







import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h1>Angular Router</h1>
      <nav>
        <a routerLink="/fullmonitor" routerLinkActive="active">Full monitor</a>
        <a routerLink="/kpi" routerLinkActive="active">KPI </a>
      </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `

})
export class AppComponent { }
```

here is a link to  the plunkr i created. I am trying to create a navbar in angular 2 and i am using ng-bootstrap to use bootstrap styles in my angular 2 app however i cannot get anything to load in the webpage it always says loading.... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please start your Plunker from a template like the one provide by Plunker itself and put the files in the appropriate sub-folder. In Plunker you can rename files by double-clicking them. A `/` if the name contains `/` the parts between are used like folders.

Comment: whats wrong with the way i have it set up? its producing the same results?

Comment: The implementation files are normally in a subfolder `app` or `src`.

Comment: ahh i see ok i will do that

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: @sizz, while you're working on getting node_modules working on plunkr, what do you see in your browser inspector?  Is it 'clean'?

Comment: i am getting a lot of 404 errors however all the files are located in the project folder so im getting confused why it is not referencing correctly

Comment: Have you run 'npm install' per your package.json and the node_modules that are referenced actually exist?

Comment: yes i have done that and the node modules are loaded i moved the html pages out of the app and into the project folder and now im getting errors saying ngtab does not exist but i followed the instructions on this https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started and it should work right?

Comment: i found a mistake i had i did not include NgbModule in the imports in my app.module.ts file! Thank you now on to the next problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake i had made was not having NgbModule in the app.module.ts imports!